# CURL -F file push -> convert to equivalent PowerShell Invoke-RestMethod

Tags: powershell, curl

I have seen a ton of attempts to do this in Stack Overflow, but none of the approaches have worked for me (and many others). But it seems like a simple thing to do:

This curl command works fine in powershell.

```
function curlPush() {
    $url = "$post_url/$dset_id/transactions/$trid"
    $header = "Authorization: Bearer $token"
    curl.exe --request POST --url $url --header $header -F file="@$folder_path"
}
```

However the equivalent using Invoke-RestMethod gives an error:

```
function pushFile() {
    $url = "$post_url/$dset_id/transactions/$trid"
    $header = @{
        'Authorization' = "Bearer $token"
        'Content-Type' = 'multipart/form-data'
    }
    $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -header $header -Method POST -InFile $folder_path
    if (!$?) {
        Write-Host $_.ErrorDetails.Message
    }
    $response
}
```

The error returned is:

```
Invoke-RestMethod : {"errorCode":"INVALID_ARGUMENT","errorName":"Default:InvalidArgument","errorInstanceId":"0bc80c74-35ae-4837-a87e-ff0e214b451b","parameters":{}}
At C:\Users\Documents\Software Projects\SolarWinds\PushFiles.ps1:42 char:17
+ ... $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -header $header -Method POST  ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You show two different commands, the headers are different.

Comment: If you mean the Content-Type, well I have tried them both with and without, No difference.

Comment: I always just get it working in postman then you can export as curl, invoke-restmethod or whatever. Makes life easier.

Comment: @OwainEsau this sounded like a really smart approach to me. Unfortunately, What postman tries to do is build the multipart/form body with string building, but that is giving a lot of errors: Unable to find type [System.Net.Http.MultipartFormDataContent]. Unable to find type [System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue].